# Can someone explain the term "commonly owned"?

Tags: prior-art, claims, filing

As seen in a patent application, can someone please explain to a layperson what this term means?

"All claims of the present invention application are **commonly owned**."

I am having a heck of a time finding anything on this using Google.
Thanks.

Comment: "Commonly owned" means owned by the same entity; i.e. person or business.  Could you provide more context for the quoted sentence?  Common ownership can have implications for obviousness and double patenting for instance.